# How do I expand the appbar after pulling 2 times?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, appbar

I want my app to only expand the app bar after pulling the screen 2 times when it reaches the beginning of the scroll

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3ylA.gif)

EDIT:

I will try to improve the question. How do I get the starting position of a recycle view or a viewpager2.  So when the position is 0 (Starting position), I want the appbar not to expand, now to expand it has to pull down while in position 0

Comment: You have to provide some code. How are we supposeded to answer your question? Maybe don't pull down bar two times...

Comment: But I don't know how to do it, how will I provide a code? I left a gif that shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it through the following commands

```
AtomicBoolean firstBoot = new AtomicBoolean(true);
recycleView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        if (firstBoot.get) {
            firstBoot.set(false);
            return;
        }
        if (recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset() == 0){
            recyclerView.stopScroll();
            bar.setExpanded(false);
        }
    }
});
```

The variable "firstBoot" is so that the method is not executed when the activity is created